# Dismiss pushed view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, dismiss

So I have a view controller which I display as follows:

```
func showProfileForTrainer(trainer: Trainers) {
    let viewPTProfileVC = ViewPTProfileVC()
    viewPTProfileVC.trainer = trainer
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewPTProfileVC, animated: true)
}
```

But when trying to dismiss the view, I cannot get it to work. It has a back button in a navigation bar which functions fine, but when trying to dismiss the view via a button for example, it does nothing. I have currently tried:

```
func handleMessageTrainer() {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        print(1)
        self.tabBarVC?.showChatLogForTrainer(trainer: self.trainer!)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        print(2)
        self.tabBarVC?.showChatLogForTrainer(trainer: self.trainer!)
    }
    navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print(3)
        self.tabBarVC?.showChatLogForTrainer(trainer: self.trainer!)
    })
    self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print(4)
        self.tabBarVC?.showChatLogForTrainer(trainer: self.trainer!)
    })
    print(5)
}
```

As you can see I have tried varying ways and none work, and the console just outputs `5`.

Frustratingly, elsewhere in my app I presented a view in the same way as shown at the beginning and it dismissed fine using `dismiss(animated: true) { ... }`

Any idea why it won't work here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You must *pop* the view controller from the corresponding navigation controller:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `pushviewcontroller method` then to `dismiss` you have to use `popviewcontroller method`.

**Try this:**

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Well now don't I feel silly!
Is there a way to pop a view with a completion method, like you can with dismiss?

Comment: Popviewcontroller does not have completion method.

Comment: But you can check viewwilldisappear method